# Can an optional LESS mixin variable refer to another variable

Tags: less, mixins

Is it possible to refer to another variable in a parametric mixin?

```
.button(@textColor : @white, @iconColor : @textColor) {
    color: @textColor;
    i {
        color: @iconColor
    }
}
```

I want `@iconColor` to default to the value of `@textColor`.

The LESS compiler is complaining.

Comment: what is the use of the second parameter in your mixin? You are not using it anywhere? Can't you just remove it, compiling should go fine then.

Comment: My mistake, I've updated the code snippet.

Comment: @BenFoster: I've updated my answer to reflect your clearer code update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to do a nested mixin idea to get your functionality you want. LESS cannot tell that you have already set the `@textColor` and use that as the default setting for the second parameter. Instead, you need to do some type of guard expression. Here, I have made that guard expression a nested mixin that evaluates the second parameter within the main mixin and responds accordingly to get the `@iconColor` set:

```
.button(@textColor: @white, @setIconColor: null) {

    .setDefault() when (@setIconColor = null) {
       .doSetting(@textColor);
    }
    .setDefault() when (iscolor(@setIconColor)) {
       .doSetting(@setIconColor);
    }
    .setDefault();

    .doSetting(@iconColor) {    
        color: @textColor;
        i {
          color: @iconColor
        }
    }
}
```